# Python pandas dataframe 'SUMIF' - criteria range differs from sum range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a question regarding Pandas DataFrame calculations.

I need a code that follows the logic of a SUMIF function in Excel 
(`Criteria`, `Criteria_Range`, `Sum_Range`).

I have a `df_Crit` (1 column), then I have a `df_crit_rng` (contains 10 columns) and a df_sum_rng (10 columns). All with the same length (depending on the file up to 4 mio rows).

Here is a snippet of the data for the first 5 columns of criteria and sum range (unfortunately bids4 & bids5 are not visible):

```
                       |-------------crit_range---------|  |---sum range-------|
            crit       bidp1  bidp2  bidp3  bidp4  bidp5  bids1  bids2  bids3  \
0        3584.707646   3586   3585   3584   3583   3582    239    638    301   
1        3584.707646   3586   3585   3584   3583   3582    239    638    301   
2        3584.707646   3586   3585   3584   3583   3582    240    638    301   
3        3584.707646   3586   3585   3584   3583   3582    240    638    301   
4        3584.707646   3586   3585   3584   3583   3582    240    638    301   
5        3584.707646   3586   3585   3584   3583   3582    240    638    301   
...              ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...   
1078486  3593.203398   3594   3593   3592   3591   3590    604    663    649   
1078487  3593.203398   3594   3593   3592   3591   3590    604    663    649
```

Now the function should check:

```
if df_crit <= df_criteria_range
```

then sum df_sum_rng up to the columns where the statement is true for df_critera_range.

for Row 0 means, it should sum `bids1` + `bids2`, as `bidp1` & `bidp2` are larger than the criteria in that row.

Finally, it should create a CSV outfile with that calculation.

**What is the pandasic way to do that? I guess I need an efficient way here without looping through the dataframes as the files are huge?**

Comment: Can you show us your latest attempt(s) [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52139725/edit)? Otherwise, this question is likely too broad and we can't reasonably pinpoint the part which you find difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a boolean mask and summing the values where the mask is `True`:

Say these are the columns of interest:

```
bidp = df[['bidp1', 'bidp2', 'bidp3']]
bids = df[['bids1', 'bids2', 'bids3']]
```

Build a mask for `bids`:

```
mask = pd.concat([bidp[column] > df.crit for column in bidp], axis=1, keys=bids.columns)
```

Mask, filling with `0` where mask is `False` and sum across columns:

```
result = bids[mask].fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```

This is the column of sums of the `bids` values for the `bidp` values that exceed `crit`. You can add it to your dataframe and save the result to csv:

```
df['conditional_sum'] = result
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey! Worked perfectly :)